# How to run macro to only one computer

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba form . I wanted to know if there's a way for it to run only in a single computer so that if someone want's to copy it they cannot run it on another machine.  I'm thinking maybe we can use a computer's mac address as a mode of security.

Anyone?

---

EDIT: implemented example from [miroxlav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44610083/2392157):

```
Const AllowedName As String = "CEB-L1-7440236"

Sub UserForm_click()
    If Environ$("COMPUTERNAME") <> AllowedName Then
        MsgBox ("Not authorized.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If vbYes <> MsgBox("Launch the macro?", vbYesNo) Then Exit Sub

    '--start of code what macro actually does
    '....
    '....
    '....
    '--end of code what macro actually does

    MsgBox ("Finsihed.")

End Sub
```

Comment: Password protect the code and then use Environ(x) to identify the username or the computer?

Comment: I see.. so the file would check to see the windows login or user account., correct? don't know how to code it.

Comment: For example, declare `Dim x as String`, then use `x = Environ("computername")` now you can check that x = a specific computer name

Comment: Hi please check the code above..that code enclose in "" is my computer name..but i'm still getting the error...

Comment: @Zhamepace – I edited your question to correct the code you provided. It should help you. You can later remove lines with `MsgBox` "Launch the macro?" and "Finished", their purpose is mainly to help you in better understanding of code flow. If you are getting any error, please be specific. (And first do some searching to resolve it autonomously.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Embed computer name into your VBA code and add a test for it.
2. Password-protect the code module so someone else cannot see/modify it.

Maybe you would want to lock the macro rather to user name than to computer name (so the authorized user can use it on any computer), but it's on you.

```vb
' computer name
? Environ$("COMPUTERNAME")

' alternative: user name
? Application.UserName
```

Example - inset `Const` line at the top of your macro module and `If`...`EndIf` just after your `Sub` macro line:

```vb
Const AllowedName As String = "abcd"
Sub UserForm_click()
    If Environ$("COMPUTERNAME") <> AllowedName Then
        MsgBox ("Not authorized.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '--keep your original code here--
End Sub
```

But this one can be relatively easily circumvented using command line:

```vb
SET COMPUTERNAME=abcd
```

once someone knows that `abcd` is proper computer name needed to run the macro. Perhaps prefer user name checking. Relevant code line will change to:

```vb
If Application.UserName <> AllowedName Then
```

Of course, you can also get computer's MAC address using VBA, just search "mac address vba", there are many examples.

Comment: Hi where to add the code??is that in UserForm_click()

Comment: try it on UserForm_Initialise()

Comment: @jamheadart – just insert it where it makes the most sense for you.

Comment: I still got an error message..I put all the codes in username initialize. by the way this is a domain computer. I added the code in my header post (added a code)

Comment: The 1st line of code that you post, I added it to username initialize and then the 2nd code is in module.i'm not sure if that is correct..please help me.